# How to simulate the Hypergeometric distribution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulation, probability, distribution, distributed-computing

i want to simulate in Matlab program the Hypergeometric distribution with probability mass function and parameters as described here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution 
how can i code that while producing random numbers from uniform distribution.

Comment: Why do you want to code it, when [Matlab provides a generator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hygernd.html)?

Comment: @pjs Heh, good catch!

Comment: @pjs i have to do it with the distrubution function, not with the generator, sorry for not mention it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily done with the [`randperm`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) function, which generates a **sample without replacement**.

Let the distribution parameters be defined as follows:

```
N = 10; % population size
K = 3;  % number of success states in the population
n = 5;  % number of draws
```

Then the variable `k` obtained as

```
k = sum(randperm(N,n)<=K);
```

has a hypergeometric distribution with parameters `N`,`K`,`n`.

---

If you really need to use a **uniform** random number generator ([`rand`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) function):

```
[~, x] = sort(rand(1,N));
x = x(1:n); % this gives the same result as randperm(N,n)
k = sum(x<=K);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most sensible would be to use the [builtin hypergeometric generator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hygernd.html).

If you have to do this for an assignment or some other arbitrary reason, the generic solution when an inverse CDF exists is to do inversion—use the uniform generator to create a p-value (a value between 0 and 1), and plug that into the inverse CDF.  Since [Matlab provides an inverse CDF function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hygeinv.html), this should be straightforward.